# Understanding : git push --set-upstream "refspec" with and without prefixing "HEAD"

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, upstream-branch

I have local git branch `<BRANCH_NAME>` that has no reference to upstream origin. I have made some  changes to local branch and *committed* the same locally. I am now trying to push to remote origin.

1. When I tried: 
   `git push --set-upstream origin <BRANCH_NAME>`  it throws the error :

```
error:src refsprc <LOCAL_BRANHC_NAME> does not match any 
error: failed to push some refs to '<REMOTE_URL>
```

2. When i tried 
   `git push --set-upstream origin **HEAD:**<BRANCH_NAME>` it succeeded

The difference between the commands is the prefixing of **HEAD:** to the "BRANCH_NAME". So my question is :

1. What's difference between pushing with/without the prefix "HEAD" ?
2. Would be helpful if I can get pictorial representation of what's happening behind the git commands for my better understanding.
3. Let me know if more information is required from my end for clarification.

NOTE:

- I do understand what is HEAD. It points to the latest commit of the
  current branch.
- I did try the `cat .git/HEAD` and the output was `ref: refs/heads/<BRANCH_NAME>` - which is the correct one.
- I noted in some answers of stackoverflow, it was mentioned to do `git commit` . I had tried the commit approach as well and faced the same error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the ouput of a `git status`: you won't be in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) mode, but you can see if you have untracked files that could be added/committed (as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793757/6309)).

Check also the output of `git branch -avv` to see both local and remote branches.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
1. I did check out the "git commit"  related answers. As I have mentioned, I did "git commit" locally and then only tried the "git push". 
2. For ```git branch -avv```, since it is new local branch, there is no upstream for <BRANCH_NAME>

Comment: @Sriram Can you add the list of branches (and tags if you have some) to the question, just to check for anyhting peculiar in that list? (`git branch -l`, `git tag -l`)